# How to block the drop down in IE6

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer-6

In my project I am using the update progress bar. When the button is clicked the background page will be disabled. It works fine in IE7, Firefox and Chrome. But in IE6 the dropdown is displaying behind the progress bar. Can any one help me to solve this problem. Here the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="fp_t012stk.aspx.vb" Inherits="fp_t012stk" title="Current Stock Report" %>


   <asp:UpdateProgress id="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
<progresstemplate>

<div id="Layer1" style="top:45px; left:0px; width:80%; height:100%; z-index:1; background:gray; display:block; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; padding:130px; font: 18px/1.6 Times New Roman; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color:Gray;filter: alpha(opacity=60); opacity: 0.1; width:76%; height:100%; overflow:auto; text-decoration:none; color:Black; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0%; margin-left:-10px"> 


                <asp:Image ID="imgloading" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader2.gif" /><br /> 
            </div> 


</progresstemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a client request to support IE6?

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with Babak's direction... If IE6 is not a required support item, I would not code for it. IE6 is VERY old and would be used by clients running Windows 9x. Even the most basic computer users are using Windows XP on average (I work at a support firm and it's been at least 5 years since we received a Windows 9x or IE6 call).

Answer (score 0):

Check your html output. And see if the z-index of the dropdown and the progress bar style values. May be both are having 1, or dropdown a lesser value ( 0 , -1) . try specifying the lowest value to the progress bar style than the other controls.

Comment: Before this i didnt set any z index but it wotks fine in mozila and ie6

Comment: yeah but how different browsers interpret styles may be different. specially ie 6. so give it a try..