# The Progress displays behind the dropdown

Tags: asp.net

In my project I am using the update progress bar. When the button is clicked the background page will be disabled. It works fine in IE7, Firefox and Chrome. But in IE6 the dropdown is displaying behind the progress bar. Can any one help me to solve this problem. Here the code:

**<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="fp_t012stk.aspx.vb" Inherits="fp_t012stk" title="Current Stock Report" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

function ShowProgress()
   {
  document.getElementById('').style.display = "inline";

   }

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <contenttemplate>
```

All
                                                Good
                                                Defective
                                                OOW Good
                                                OOW Defective
                                             
                                                No
                                                Yes

```
                                        <asp:Button id="btnReport" runat="server" CssClass="css_button" __designer:wfdid="w132" Text="PRINT" OnClientClick="ShowProgress()"></asp:Button></TD><TD align=left><asp:Button id="btnExcel" runat="server" CssClass="css_button" __designer:wfdid="w133" Text="Excel"></asp:Button></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></asp:Panel> </TD><TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Processing........

**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489530/how-to-block-the-drop-down-in-ie6/6489679#6489679

Comment: Sorry, is something missing? I don't see any dropdown (ie. combobox) in your code?

Comment: Instead of posting a duplicate question, edit your previously asked question if you need it corrected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a dropdown in your code, but you can try setting the z-index higher to make it appear above other elements.

```
style="z-index: 1000;"
```

Comment: Wont work. A bug in IE6 means drop-down lists are always on top and ignore z-index